# Qt Creator gives me an error when linking to OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator, qmake

I have a simple OpenCV program found on the web. I am trying to compile it in Qt creator. The source code is the following (main.cpp):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
        if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
            return -1;

        Mat edges;
        namedWindow("edges",1);
        for(;;)
        {
            Mat frame;
            cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
            cvtColor(frame, edges, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.0, 1.0);
            Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
            imshow("edges", edges);
            if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
        }
        // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
        return 0;
}
```

Here's my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv

SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_shape -lopencv_videoio
```

When I build the project, I get the following linker error (plus other similar ones):

```
error: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)'
```

However, when using a simple CMake file, it builds and runs perfectly. My CMakeLists.txt is pretty simple:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Are there some other paths I need to set up?

Comment: So, let me understand - the problem is that with the *CMake* file linking works but with the *.Pro* file it does not. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Then, for that I added the *qmake* tag. Qt-Creator works well with both *CMake* and *qmake*. The difference you are seeing is because of qmake, which uses the *.pro* files.

Comment: I maybe wrong but you need to add something like `QT       += core` `QT       -= gui` `QT  += widgets` to your pro file.

Comment: Try: LIBS += `pkg-config opencv --libs`

Comment: "Try: LIBS += pkg-config opencv --libs" - this didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The reason this happened to me is that first I did

```
sudo apt install libopencv-highgui-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```

and then compiled OpenCV 2.4.13 from sources and installed it (because I needed exactly this version).

With cmake, it linked to OpenCV 4.1.0, but with Qt Creator it linked to OpenCV 2.4.13. The solution was to uninstall OpenCV and install version 2.4.13 only.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check that you have installed all the dependencies of OpenCV. Probably you will need to install `FFmpeg` too.

Then replace:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_shape -lopencv_videoio
```

By this:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_shape -lopencv_videoio
```

You also need to add the specific OpenCV configuration:

```
CONFIG += opencv
```

Or alternatively:

```
unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

It works for me with those small changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, after trying these changes, I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

I m also working on Qt with Opencv and I added opencv into Qt using these lines to `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Also you should check the opencv installation via on terminal:

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

If it gives error then something wrong with the installation.

**Edit:** If you installed opencv4.x.x, you should change the word `"opencv"` on commands above with the `"opencv4"`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CONFIG += opencv


INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv4
```